# Retrieving SP Calendar Items

Tags: 2010, caml-query, sharepoint-calendar

Using CAML query, I have this requirement to retrieve items from calendar list where date is neither an Event Date nor an End Date but exists in a span of {Event & End} time like so:

[image: Calendar View]

I have tried creating a CAML query but unable to get a handle on retrieving the **selected item in the above image** where date i am querying is **2/18/2015.**

Can some one point me in the right direction in writing a CAML query which help me retrieve the selected item by passing **2/18/2015** date as query value for Start/End time fields?

Comment: I'd recomment grabbing the BIWUG CAML Designer from here, http://www.biwug.be/resources.

Comment: So you want to input a date (say 2/18/2015) and you want to retrieve all the items that the input date falls between items' "START TIME" and "END TIME" column values. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes @PaimanSamadian

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the internal names of the columns "Start Time" and "End Time". I will assume they are "StartTime" and "EndTime" respectively. Hence:

```
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='StartTime' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2015-02-18</Value>
         </Lt>
         <Gt>
            <FieldRef Name='EndTime' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2015-02-18</Value>
         </Gt>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

To find a field's internal name: [How to get Internal names of columns in sharepoint lists](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/75ca6fab-56f3-4bf4-aae0-2d29821778a2/how-to-get-internal-names-of-columns-in-sharepoint-lists)